# SQL Server 2014 - SQL Case statement on columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

This is the table I have :

[image: ORIGINAL TABLE]

For every unique TID, there are 2 records. For a unique TID if both records in a field is populated I want the name of the field. For example, for T01 : Field2 and Field4 have both records populated.

My current approach is I create a column with comma separated values with the field names :

```
INSERT INTO TEMP
SELECT *, 
       (CASE WHEN COUNT(IIF(Field1 IS NOT NULL,1,NULL)) = 2 THEN 'FIELD1' ELSE 'NO' END) + ',' +
       (CASE WHEN COUNT(IIF(Field2 IS NOT NULL,1,NULL)) = 2 THEN 'FIELD2' ELSE 'NO' END) + ',' +
       (CASE WHEN COUNT(IIF(Field3 IS NOT NULL,1,NULL)) = 2 THEN 'FIELD3' ELSE 'NO' END) + ',' +
       (CASE WHEN COUNT(IIF(Field4 IS NOT NULL,1,NULL)) = 2 THEN 'FIELD4' ELSE 'NO' END) AS ATTR
FROM ORIGINAL_TABLE;
```

I then convert the comma separated column into multiple records :

```
SELECT *, S.ITEMS as ATTRIBUTES
FROM TEMP
CROSS APPLY DBO.SPLIT(ATTR, ',') S
WHERE S.ITEMS NOT LIKE '%NO%'
```

Consider T101 of the result obtained from above command,  This gives me the output :

[image: Result I got]

Edit : Apologies. It should be Field2 instead of Field1.

This does give me information on the fields for every unique TID that follows the condition but I want it to be more specific. I run this for very big data with over 100 columns so this approach is slow.

Is there a way to get this? Where I display just the fields that satisfy the condition and their values for both records in T101.

[image: Expected Result]

Edit : Apologies. It should be Field2 instead of Field1 in the table.

I am fairly new to SQL, any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: what basis you are selecting field1 and field4 only?

Comment: Every unique TID has two records. In case of T101 as well. Field2 and Field4 both have not null values in both their records for T101

Comment: Field2 is also not null for T01 ...so why do you eliminate it from resultset?

Comment: do you need fields name or data as you shown in last table dialgram?

Comment: My apologies. It should be Field2 and Field4 in the resulting table.

Comment: I would like the data as shown in the last table. But for the time being my method helps me find the field names. I was wondering if there is a way in which I can get the data as seen in the last table.

Comment: okay let me try

Comment: Also I would like to know if there is a better way in getting the field names as well. Since my approach is very slow for large number of records.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is rather complicated, and I'm not 100% sure what you really want.  But based on:

> For a unique TID if both records in a field is populated I want the name of the field.

You can unpivot and aggregate.  Assuming that your columns all have a similar data type, you can use:

```
SELECT t.tId, v.fieldname
FROM ORIGINAL_TABLE t CROSS APPLY
     (VALUES ('Field1', Field1), 
             ('Field2', Field2), 
             ('Field3', Field3), 
             ('Field4', Field4)
     ) v(fieldname, val)
GROUP BY t.tID, v.fieldname
HAVING COUNT(*) = COUNT(v.val)  -- all populated
```

Comment: But I want only the fields where both the records for T101 is not null. This statement gives me all the field names.

Comment: @dithyasridharan . . . The `having` clause should be doing that.  You could replace it with `count(v.val) = 2` if you wanted to ensure exactly two records.  I used `count(*)` instead so it would scale to any number of records for each id.